# Should I change my diet based on rice and vegetables?

Tags: diet, weight-gain

I'm a very busy person so I can't spend an hour a day cooking things, so six month ago I made a method which consisted of having vegetables already cut in the fridge and every time I need to eat I just cook rice with a rice cooker and add those.

this takes me 5 mins per meals and it's a huge time gainer but I fear this is not the best thing to do. I'm not really good at nutrition so I kind of have no idea of what I'm doing.

Right now I basically eat for dinner :

- 300 gr of rice with 100 gr of quinoa
- 1 Cup  of carrots and Broccoli
- 100 gr of lentils

I've been eating this for 6 month and I don't really mind but I classify myself as an ectomorph and **I can't seem to gain weight with this**.

should I change it ? And if so, how ?

Ps : I know this meal looks like a vegetarian's one but I'm not, I just find it convenient.

Thanks a lot in advance !

---

edit :
Thanks for the answers, you raised a lot of imprecisions in my first post, so here you can find some more info :

at breakfast I usually drink a milkshake of :

- One banana
- 70 gr of this : http://www.myprotein.com/sports-nutrition/total-breakfast/10530574.html?_ga=1.78190164.1717126440.1462449839&countrySelected=Y
- The issue is that at lunch I eat a lot of various things as I have to eat with my coworkers but it's usually the fish of the day (around 150 gr of it) with vegetables and rice
- After workout I drink this ( one cup) : https://www.prozis.com/fr/en/optimum-nutrition/serious-mass-6-lbs-2721g with water or milk if I'm at home.

I'm 20, I am 1m84 tall for 68 kg and I sleep 6 hours a day

I go to the gym 2 days a week for upper and lower body using freeletics for the actual program.

Comment: I updated my answer, have another review.

Answer (score 1):

edit: Now we are getting somewhere!

Lets break it down (credit: myfitnesspal/reddit) before I show you your meal, I added your targets at the bottom of the breakdown. I used the information provided, slammed it into iifym.com which is pretty well established as a good way to inform dieting and I got the following macro breakdown:

[image: Lots of calories!]

I chose the options I did because they are the safest options and are the ones I, any many others, have successfully used to get lean gains.

Lets look at the food now we have some targets. Is your mass gainer and protein shake making you up to your macro needs for the day?

[image: Nope]

Not even close. (You said 1 cup of mass gainer which I took as 1 scoup, if you are using a whole cupful you have more issues.

Looking at each macronutrient:

- Calories total: Still under eating but not by much. This is your key to understanding why you aren't putting on weight fast.
- Carbs: For someone doing 2 sessions of exercise per week you are eating far too many carbs. Carry on like this and you will gain only fat.
- Protein: For 2 sessions a week doing exercise your number is slightly below what I would expect you needing. But, as you are bulking you are MASSIVELY under. You cannot use shakes and powered to get there, you need to eat lean meat like fish and lean chicken.
- Fat: You could do to add more fat.

Get some chicken breast, flavour, grill and refrigerate/freeze portions. 2 mins in microwave will reheat it. 1 cup of chicken breast is about 40g protein.

Beyond that please go and read my post here about how to gain weight: [Diet chart to gain 10-12kg weight](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/31181/diet-chart-to-gain-10-12kg-weight)

So what should your meals look like? Although I have 2 shakes each day when bulking which isn't optimal, I struggle to meet my protein macro with regularity. I sometimes skip one shake and add a extra portion (4oz) cod fillet for dinner but I still get all the nutrition I need from my food. Note, I pair my bulk with 4-5 days a week exercise, for at least an hour each time at a high intensity. I also take creatine and vitamin D, C and Zinc.

[image: Here's me trying same diet.]

Answer (score 1):

As JJosaur pointed out, this meal is around 520 calories. However, this number is utterly useless unless we know more about you. What do you weigh, do you exercise? if so, what do you do? how often? how old are you, how much sleep do you get? you get the point. Although he mentions that you should eat protein, which you definitely should if your goal is muscle gain, you won't actually gain much of anything unless you break down the muscles through exercise to gain weight.

I'll make it very simple though, in order to gain weight, you must consume more calories than you burn off. Everyone burns a certain amount of calories via their resting metabolic rate, which is around 14-15x your bodyweight in lbs, i.e if you weighed 180lbs, you would burn 2500-2700 calories a day just to get your body to function. Hence, your meals throughout the day must not only reach this amount of calories, but they must SURPASS them in order to gain weight on a regular basis. This means you would need to eat 3000-35000 calories if you weigh 180lbs, daily, over a certain period of time, in order to gain any weight at all. Now, the macros that comprise your foods will have an impact on how your body looks, i.e 90% of your calories coming from carbs and fats won't make you the most muscular guy in the world, but you will still gain weight. Ideally, you'd want to lift weights regularly (at least 2-3x a week), and get over 30% of your calories from protein, and the rest can vary depending on your lifestyle, if you want to gain weight via as much muscle as possible.